# Creating a stored procedure SQL

Tags: mysql, procedure

I have this codec and I need to make it into a stored procedure. I know the basics of it and am still new to the concept so I apologize for asking but once I see my error I can take it into a good learning experience if anyone can help solve my problem. This is the codec I have.

```
  CREATE PROC spGetCancelDate

  AS

  Begin

     SELECT  c.program_id, d.dealer_code,b.last_name As DealerName, a.account_no, a.vin, ((e.last_name)+','+(e.first_name)) As Name, 
a.cancel_refund_date, a.purchase_date,a.miles, a.duration,a.sale_price,a.number_of_payments,  a.sales_tax, a.downpayment

from tDealer d 

Join tContact b ON d.contact_id = b.contact_id 

Join tContract a On d.dealer_id = a.dealer_id 

Join tCompany c ON d.company_id= c.company_id

Join tContact E On e.contact_id = a.contact_id

Where c.program_id = @program And a.cancel_refund_date Between @BeginDate And @Endate

End
```

Comment: What errors does this throw? And where did you get it from? The statment "CREATE PROC" creates a stored procedure.

Comment: Well the problem is I don't have permission to use the stored procedure yet. So I am trying to create it just to see if the format is correct until I have permission.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to test a stored procedure and syntax ect when you have nothing to run it off.

Read through the following link and learn about how they are made.

Once you have created the proc because you aren't creating/updating anything you can have a play around until it works worry free.

Basically a stored procedure is a saved script for either selecting, updating, inserting or deleting records. Very useful if you are going to execute the same SQL over and over again.

Creating:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html

Altering: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/alter-procedure.html